Set different column widths for FullCalendar JS in Resource View
I'm using FullCalendar JS version 3. It doesn't seem to have a feature for setting different column widths for resources in resource view. I haven't found a way of doing it using options. ChatGPT suggested this:
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
  // ...
  columnHeader: {
    dow: [
      { width: 200 }, 
      { width: 150 },
      { width: 100 },
      { width: 100 },
      { width: 100 },
      { width: 100 },
      { width: 80 }
    ]
  }
});

It didn't work. If it does work, it probably just works in other views, not the resources view.
If I want to achieve this by modifying fullcalendar.js itself, which function do I modify. Yes, I know this is not the ideal way of adding features, but that's what I'm choosing to do. Where do I edit?
Edit: Upgrading to the latest Fullcalendar is not an option in this particular case.

columnHeader in v3 is just a true/false field, as documented. Not sure where you got the idea you can declare an object for that option. Don't guess...read the docs. AI clearly didn't read the docs either - because it's basically a sophisticated guessing machine. You can use it to assist you and speed you up, if you already basically know what you're doing - but you have to check everything it gives you and not just blindly paste it and hope! It makes mistakes all the time, because it doesn't actually know how to write code.

You might be able to use the resourceRender callback to set some CSS on the table column to control its width. I haven't tried it but it might be worth a go.

Also to be clear, are we talking about the vertical resource view in this question? Because I can't see how it would make any sense for the timeline view (seeing as the resources are in rows in the timeline, not columns).

Other than that, I don't think you have any options. You can try modifying that internals of fullCalendar.js but it will be very difficult, the code is not very clear if you haven't worked on the fullCalendar project (which I haven't).

Also bear in mind that this version is very out of date - you might be better upgrading to the current version (v6) and then forking an existing view to make a custom view where you can manipulate the rendering in a more structured way. Again though it's still a lot of work - you should carefully consider whether it's really worth it, just to make one or two columns a bit wider or narrower than the others. fullCalendar works on a grid system and spaces everything equally, which is pretty fundamental to its setup. Changing that will be hard.
